# Add two int chars together into one char array or string

Tags: c

How can i add Add two int chars together into one char array or string like :

```
char *s;
int a = 'A';
int b = 'B';
s = a + b;
```

the terminal givs me :

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from
>   'int'

Comment: What do you want to do? What is the goal you want to accomplish? To create the string `"AB"`? Perhaps you should take some time to [read a couple of good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: If you want to create the string `"AB"`, the `+` operator is *not* how you do that in C.

Comment: `s = (char[]){a, b, 0};` or `s = (char[3]){a, b};` :-)

Comment: Is it a strict requirement to have `s` be a pointer? As a pointer cannot hold nothing but just an address, there is no room for a `char`-array or a "string" in the code you show.

Comment: I am voting to close this, because there is no indication on what the OP wants - and if there was, this would be a duplicate of about 100 already answered questions.

Comment: @alk `Is it a strict requirement to have s be a pointer?` Do you think that OP knows what the pointer is? A Good book is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) to print the values to a string.

```
char my_cstring[32] = "";
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';
sprintf(my_cstring, "%c%c", a, b);
// output: "AB"
```

Comment: "*`5`*", "*`9`*"? What?

Comment: So far the OP hasn't really explained what he's trying to do, but the consensus among answerers so far is that he'd probably want `%c` in your solution, not `%d`.

Comment: He is probably coming from a language like C# or JavaScript where the `+` operator automatically performs a `.ToString` and concatenates the arguments into a string.